# How to Only Add Objects with Distinct Attributes to Core Data to-many Relationship NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Suppose that I have a core data entity ShapesEntry which contains several relationships:

- shapeInstances (to-many w/ ShapeInstance Entity)
- sideCounts (to many w/ String_Container Entity)
- edgeLengths (to many w/ String_Container Entity)
- colors (to many w/ String_Container Entity)

The ShapeInstance entity has three attributes: numSides, edgesLength, color. Inverse to ShapeEntry.

The String_Container entity has one attribute: stringValue. Inverse to ShapeEntry.

The purpose of ShapesEntry is to contain all instances of existing shapes, as well as to keep track of the distinct numSides, edgesLengths, and colors that every recorded shape instance uses.

For example:

- (Triangle): 3-5-RED
- (Square): 4-5-GREEN
- (Square): 4-10-BLUE
- (Pentagon): 3-10-GREEN

^ After adding these shape instances, GameEntry should include each of these four Shape objects, and the NSSet relationships to sideCounts, edgeLengths, and colors should include {3, 4}, {5, 10}, and {RED, GREEN, BLUE}, respectively.

HOWEVER, because String_Container is an object...

```
String_Container *sides = [NSEntity Description insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"String_Container" inManagedObjectContext:context];
sides.stringValue = shapeInstance.numSides; //or edgesLength or color
[shapeEntry addSideCounts:sides];
```

...the above code renders sideCounts, edgeLengths, and colors of {3, 4, 4, 3}, {5, 5, 10, 10}, and {RED, GREEN, BLUE, GREEN} and the addObject method does not recognize them as distinct.

I COULD fetch the appropriate ShapeEntry (this example is dumbed down, so only 1 of these exists here, but in my code you could have thousands), iterate through the existing attributes for each of the relationships and confirm that the value I want to add does not already exist BUT that seems awfully expensive when what I really want is for the relationship to act like an NSSet from the get-go. I do recognize that technically the relationship is doing its job because the objects I want to add are 'distinct objects' despite having identical attribute values, but I would like it to go a step deeper and confirm that these attribute values are distinct before trying to add to the ShapeEntry relationship.

How can I accomplish this task? If my example was confusing, please ask for clarification...I made it up on the spot so hopefully my variable names are consistent...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you cache the managed object ids for each value (how many distinct values in your true data set)?

Comment: I guess so...I'm importing 32k distinct "shapes", and each shapeEntity might have between 2 and 10 distinct attributes for "sides", "lengths" and "colors", etc etc etc.  Is that actually the easiest way? Is there not some kind of comparator operation I can do?

Comment: Let me clarify my shape example by saying that perhaps each distinct shapeEntity belongs to shapes of similar name ie: Triangle, Square, Diamond, etc.  So each of those could have numerous attribute values for the given relationships.

Comment: Is it really necessary to duplicate all the information? With `[shapeEntry valueForKeyPath:@"shapeInstances.color"]` you would get a set of all used colors, similar for the other attributes.

Comment: @Marting R, this is the first time that I have ever used Core Data, so i'm not entirely aware of the depth of its functionality.  My current implementation is more or less based on the way I managed the data w/ an NSDictionary before I converted (or in the process of) to core data.  If I understand you right, the method call you suggested will return an NSSet of all the attribute values for some particular relationship? That would be amazing!  I will try this out now...

Comment: Like a charm! Thank you so much Martin.  Please answer my question with that one-liner so I can give you credit!  This saves me so much trouble. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Key-Value Coding method

```
NSSet *colors = [shapeEntry valueForKeyPath:@"shapeInstances.color"];
```

you get all color values of the shape instances related to `shapeEntry`, the same works
for the other attributes. This seems to
be easier than to duplicate all the information.

You still have the option to "cache" the `colors` set in a transient property of `ShapeEntry` if necessary.

Comment: Back with another question of similar fashion; have been browsing around trying to find it based on the valueForKeyPath method with no luck.  If I wanted to retrieve the set of all types of an attribute of all of some type of relationship of all objects of some entity, what changes to the above would be necessary? I'm basically looking for what I requested in the OP except one step further by including ALL objects of the entity, and not just one object of the entity.

Comment: Is this: [<Key Value Coding>](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html) on the right path...using shapesEntry.@shapeInstance.color? Not sure how to write this with proper syntax.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: @OneManBand: That requires a `NSFetchRequest` for the ShapeEntry entity, perhaps using `propertiesToFetch` to fetch only the relevant properties. Too complicated for a comment, but perhaps helps you to get a start!